# React hook form Issues when attempting to fetch data upon clicking select field options

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

I'm using react-hook-form and React Query to retrieve data for two select fields. The first select field is populated with data using the useQuery hook, and the second select field's options depend on the selected value of its sibling. When a new option is selected in the first field, a useMutation is triggered, sending a request to the server. If the request is successful, the resulting data is then displayed in the second field.

this is what my component look like:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useMutation, useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const FormComponent = () => {
  const { register } = useForm();
  const [areas, setAreas] = useState(false);
  //getCities is a function that Fetch data with Axios
  const cities = useQuery(["citiesList"], getCities);

  //getAreaList is a function that Fetch data with Axios
  const areaListMutation = useMutation(getAreaList, {
    onSuccess: ({ data }) => {
      setAreas(data);
    }
  });
  const handleCityChange = (event) => {
    const selectedCity = parseInt(event.target.value);

    if (selectedCity) {
      areaListMutation.mutate({ id: selectedCity });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        className="rounded-lg h-12 py-1 px-3 border border-dark-gray w-full"
        id="city"
        onChange={handleCityChange}
        {...register("city")}
      >
        <option value="">choose one</option>
        {cities ? (
          cities.map((city, index) => (
            <option key={index} value={city.id}>
              {city.name}
            </option>
          ))
        ) : (
          <option value="">There is no data!</option>
        )}
      </select>
      <select
        className="rounded-lg h-12 py-1 px-3 border border-dark-gray w-full"
        id="area"
        {...register("area")}
      >
        <option value="">choose one</option>
        {areas ? (
          areas.map((area, index) => (
            <option key={index} value={area.id}>
              {area.name}
            </option>
          ))
        ) : (
          <option value="">There is no data!</option>
        )}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormComponent;
```

the handleCityChange will never trigger and send request to API because of  {...register("city")}
What should we do for scenarios like this?